# How to test multi-region write in Cosmos DB

Tags: testing, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am going to test multi-region write functionality by writing some test code using the cosmos c# v3 SDK.

I plan to have a multi-region write enabled cosmos DB (SQL core API) with three regions. I want to write to one specific region and then read from other regions. While doing it, I want to measure performance as well.
Is there any way of implementing these type of tests? Is there any good of measuring performance such as performance metrics? I also want to vary consistency level and see latency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what type of tests you are looking to do the benchmarks in this [Cosmos DB Global Distribution Demos GitHub Repo](https://github.com/markjbrown/cosmos-global-distribution-demos) may be of some help. There's a bit of a learning curve as the benchmarks are data driven from app.config files. But once you get the URIs and keys in the app.config you should be mostly good to go.

One thing worth pointing out that changing consistency level when testing multiple writers and readers in different regions when configured for multi-region writes is meaningless because you will always have eventual consistency under those circumstances. For more information see, [Guarantees associated with consistency levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/consistency-levels#guarantees-associated-with-consistency-levels).

The other thing to call out is you cannot configure multi-region writes with strong consistency. For more information see, [Strong consistency and multiple write regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/consistency-levels#strong-consistency-and-multiple-write-regions)

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. I have few more questions related to your answer. I was wondering how out-of-order writes are handled in order (in other regions) in multi-region write setting if it only has eventual consistency level. Can readers in other regions get data in order?  What system topology does Cosmos DB use for multi-region writer? for example, star, circular, or All-to-all.

Comment: When using multi-region writes there are no order guarantees on writes ever. With single-master you get the order guarantees via consistency level. The topology is hub and spoke. All writes go to hub region and are merged, then replicated back out.

Comment: I have tested your app in repo. I failed to run MultiMasterFailover.cs. It did not get out of the while loop, checking the "exit" variable. ReadItemAsync() inside the loop keeps returning the same region as before the firewall applied even though I blocked the region ip address using the firewall. Any clue?

Comment: Another thing to add is that, say, the IP address returned/parsed from the ReadItemAsync() call's response is 13.193.153.80. After blocking the exact ip manually, I invoked the same call above. Then I get the same IP address back from the response.

Comment: Yeah multi-master failover is a tricky test to run. You have to make sure that you only fail over a secondary region. It's impossible to fail over the primary or hub region. Even then it still may not work because you're essentially faking a regional failure using a local firewall rule. It sometimes does not work correctly. Basically, there is no failover for multi-region writes anyway so the test itself is more or less meaningless.

Comment: I do not understand you last comment that "Basically, there is no failover for multi-region writes anyway so the test itself is more or less meaningless." Can you elaborate more on it? Say, we have four regions (R1, R2, R3, and R4). If R1 fails to write, Then isn't a client supposed to be re-directed to other Regions?

Comment: Yes, the client is redirected. What I meant is that unlike single-region writes where I can test BCDR by failing over regions in the service itself, the same cannot be done for multi-region writes. There is no actual service-initiated way to test fail overs.

Comment: I am trying to understand "Last Write Win" policy conflict test in your repo. In my understanding, what you 
are trying to do is to make few (say, three) doc objects with the same id and each doc object is sent to cosmos db through a different client set to a specific region. what I expect was that they all go to cosmos DB and one is accepted and the other two are rejected (returning conflict code).

Comment: (Continued from above) But, when I saw your code, you use the function, IsConflict(...). This function accepts the array of SampleCustomer-type objects. 
It enumerates and counts the number of obbject not null. 
That sounds strange to me. If there are more than one object in the array, that means createItemAsync() makes the same doc object (same id) successfully multiple times. Am I missing something here? What does it mean by conflict in this context?

Comment: (Continued from above) For the uniqueness of a document item in the database, I saw in the document that "id" makes a document object unique. Is it correct? If not, what makes document unique? Wondering a partition key value is required (as in your example).

For updating conflict resolution path and mode programmatically, I understand your example uses, CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(). 
What if I want to update the existing container?

Comment: First, I encourage you to read our docs on conflict resolution. They do a good job explaining the behavior of the service, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/conflict-resolution-policies  WRT LWW, that is not how LWW works. It works exactly as the name says. Last one there wins. It's also not supposed to throw a conflict error. If you want a conflict error, use None and allow conflicts to write to the conflict feed. With conflict feed there is one conflict and one or more documents that conflict. That is why they are in an array.

Comment: id is not unique.     id + partition key is unique.

Comment: Thank you for all the explanation. Now, it always makes sense.

Comment: Good to hear. Maybe mark that answer as correct so others can benefit from it. Thanks. :)